# jQuery Validation Plugin on Django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, validation, django-forms

I'm trying to work on a Django form client-side validation using [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), and I've bumbped into an issue.

This is my **forms.py**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given email and password.
    """

    email = forms.EmailField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'E-Mail',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'First name',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    second_name = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Last name',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Password',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }))

    password2 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Password confirmation (enter the same password as above, for verification)',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email", "first_name", "second_name", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

This is my **template**

```
<form id="user_form" method="post" action="/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}

{{ user_form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

And this is the **script** to make the validation work

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

(function($,W,D,undefined)
{
    $(D).ready(function()
    {

         //form validation rules
         $("#user_form").validate({
             rules:
             {
                email:
                {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    "remote":
                    {
                      url: '/check_email/',
                      type: "post",
                      data:
                      {
                          email: function()
                          {
                              return $('#register-form :input[name="email"]').val();
                          }
                      }
                    }
                },
                first_name:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                second_name:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                password1:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                password2:
                {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: password1,
                    minlength: 8
                }
             },
             messages:
             {
                 email:
                 {
                    remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already taken.")
                 },
             },
             submitHandler: function(form)
             {
                form.submit();
             }
         });

    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I get an error on the console: "**Uncaught ReferenceError: password1 is not defined**".
What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe that you have only one `password` field in your model. So you cannot call `fields = ("email", "first_name", "second_name", "password1", "password2")`, because it reference to Model.

Comment: Mh, I'm not sure about that, because when I remove the validation for "password2", the script works.

Answer (score 1):

This line in your JavaScript:

```
equalTo: password1,
```

...needs to be a string:

```
equalTo: 'password1',
```

Otherwise JavaScript thinks you are referring to a variable named `password1`, instead of specifying the name of the element as string.